# Image gets selected

Tags: jssor

I'm very happy with my slideshow but during navigation I get an effect I'd like to avoid. 
It's the same effect that happens in any web page when one click outside of an image, drag the mouse in a position inside of the image and release the mouse. The image gets selected and turns to blue.
In my slideshow it happens when the click on the R-L arrows is not exactly stable and produce instead a click+drag action. The image that is shown turns to blue and the result on my art gallery is quite disturbing.

Is it possible to avoid that effect ?

Thanx al lot

Marco

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following approach.

```
<style>
.noselect {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
</style>

<div id="slider1_container" class="noselect" ...>
```